# I need an additional Loader

Tags: solidity, contract-development, hardhat

I'm trying to start a react app using **NPM** to connect my SmartContracts, but using the following commands i am still getting an error:

```zsh
 $ npm start

**Failed to compile.
../node_modules/hardhat/internal/cli/ArgumentsParser.js 134:26
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (134:26)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|         throw new errors_1.HardhatError(errors_list_1.ERRORS.ARGUMENTS.MISSING_TASK_ARGUMENT, {
|           param: ArgumentsParser.paramNameToCLA(paramName),
>           task: taskName ?? "help"
|         });
|       }**
```

> Not so sure if this is a problem with hardhat or something else, would really appreciate anyone's assistance.

Comment: This could not be an issue in Hardhat but in @babel could be, I edited your code snippet with the proper format.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I am still getting the same error even after updating babel in my package.json, any alternative you could suggest to rectify this?

Comment: same error here..have you fixed?